# Make $dirty manually false for ng-form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-form like this :-

```
<div class="col-sm-4" ng-form="basicinformationform" data-ng-init="getData('basicinformation')">
      <button class="btn-small" ng-click="updateData('basicinformation')" ng-show="basicinformationform.$dirty">Update</button>
      <div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basicfirstname" ng-model="data.basicinformation[0].firstname"
                    required />
            ...............
      </div>
</div>
```

Code :-

```
 $scope.updateData = function (category) {
            switch (category) {
                case 'basicinformation':
                    $scope.categorynewdata = $scope.data.basicinformation[0];
                    break;
            Users.updateData().save(query).$promise.then(function (data) {
                    alert('Data updated successfully..!');            
        });
```

When i change some data in the form, the `update` btn appears & when user clicks the button the data is saved. I want to hide this btn when it is clicked & btn should again appear when user changes input field.

I succeeded in hiding it with jquery. but when it it hidden then it again doesn't come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular supports $setPristine() to reset the form:

```
$scope.form.$setPristine();
```

Comment: <button ng-disabled="myForm.$dirty">update</button>.  Then in your updateData() function, after successfully updating the data, call myForm.$setPristine() to reset the $dirty flags.

Comment: sorry, it should be <button ng-disabled="myForm.$pristine">update</button>. Only disable the button if the form hasn't been edited/modified yet.

Comment: This is how it worked for me....`$scope.basicinformationform.$setPristine();`.....Thanks...